# Copy initialization with conversion operator

Tags: c++, initialization

There is code in [copy_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

```
struct A 
{
  operator int() { return 12;}
};

struct B 
{
  B(int) {}
};
int main()
{
 ....
    A a;
    B b0 = 12;
//    B b1 = a; //< error: conversion from 'A' to non-scalar type 'B' requested
    B b2{a};        // < identical, calling A::operator int(), then B::B(int)
    B b3 = {a};     // <
    auto b4 = B{a}; // <
}
```

Now question is

- How does Direct initialization work in case of b2? Can Direct initialization call conversion operator?
- Why Copy initialization fails for b1? Implicitly A should be converted to int and B's constructor can be called.
- b3 is also Copy initialization but it works. Why so?

Comment: Only one implicit user conversion at a time, 2 is required for `B b1 = a;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very simple: implicit convertibility (for user-defined types) is not a *transitive* property in C++. That is, while `A` is convertible to `int`, and `int` is convertible to `B`, this does *not* by itself mean that `A` is convertible to `B`. There is no valid implicit conversion sequence from `A` to `B`, so `A` is not convertible to `B`.

Copy initialization requires implicit convertibility between the type of the initialization expression and the type being initialized. Since `A` is not convertible to `B`, `b1` doesn't compile.

Anytime you see `{}` as part of an initialization like this, then this means that the object it applies to is going to undergo some form of list initialization, which is a different process from the other forms of initialization.

`b2` does not perform "direct initialization". It performs direct ***list*** initialization, which is one of two forms of list initialization. The rules of list initialization, in this case, eventually boil down to using overload resolution on the set of constructors for `B`. There is a constructor of `B` which can be called with an `A`, since that call can happen via implicit conversion of the `A` to an `int`.

`b3` is not "copy initialization"; it is copy ***list*** initialization, which has absolutely nothing to do with "copy initialization". Copy-list-initialization is identical to direct-list-initialization with exactly two exceptions, neither of which apply to this case. So it does the same thing as `b2`.

Comment: Some implicit convertibility does transit. For example, `A` is convertible to `int` and `int` is convertible to `bool`, therefore `A` is convertible to `bool`.

Comment: @eerorika: Corrected.

Comment: Thanks Nicole for clarifying things.